# How to insert a date into SQL Server using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

This is my code that will insert data into a datagridview first then into database.

When I run the code, I get the error

> operand type clash bit is incompatible with date

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

```
    populate(txtRejectID.Text, comboBoxCardType.Text, txtEmbossName.Text, txt6CardNum.Text, txt4CardNum.Text, txtQuantity.Text, comboBoxErrorDesc.Text, embossDate.Text, txtStatus.Text)

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO dbo.RejectCard VALUES (@RejectID, @Card_Type, @Emboss_Name, @Card_Number, @Quantity, @Error_Description, @Emboss_Date, @Status)"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RejectID", row.Cells("rejectid").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Card_Type", row.Cells("cardtype").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emboss_Name", row.Cells("embossname").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Card_Number", row.Cells("cardnumber").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", row.Cells("quantity").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Error_Description", row.Cells("errordescription").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emboss_Date", row.Cells("emboss_Date").Value = embossDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", row.Cells("status").Value)

                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
                Finally
                    conn.Close()
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    Next

    MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.")
End Sub
```

Comment: do mention column list in Insert which referenced to Values list same order as values. It is best practice though...

Comment: There's so much wrong there that I'm struggling to work out where to start.  Why would you create a new connection for every record?  You shouldn't even be creating a new command for every record.  If you're determined to call `ExecuteNonQuery` then you should be creating one connection and one command, adding all the paremeters, opening the connection and THEN starting the loop.  In the loop, you set the `Value` of each parameter and call then execute.  Even better, just create a `DataTable` and bind it to the grid, then save the lot with one `Update` call.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I refer my coding from here and there then implement it on my project. I will improve my coding skills. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You insert dates exactly the same way as you insert anything else.  The problem is that you're not inserting a `Date`.  You're inserting a `Boolean`.  Look at your code.  This is the value your inserting:

```
row.Cells("emboss_Date").Value = embossDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

That's an equality comparison.  The result of an equality comparison is always a `Boolean`, i.e. `True` if the values are equal and `False` if they're not.  If you want to insert a `Date` then provide a `Date`, not a comparison between a value from a grid row and a `String`.

Why aren't you just doing for that parameter exactly what you're doing for all the rest?  You clearly think you're achieving something there but I can assure you that you're not.  If what you're trying to do is drop the time from your `DateTime` value then you do that by getting the `Date` property, not by converting the `Date` to a `String`.